# scanf string in assembly

Tags: assembly, scanf

I'm trying to scan 100-sized string in assembly and to print it, using scanf and printf.

```
        .data
strString:  .string "%s"
stringToRev:    .space  100
.text   #the beginning of the code
.globl  main    #the label "main" is used to state the initial point of this program

    .type   main, @function # the label "main" representing the beginning of a function
main:   # the main function:
    pushl   %ebp    #save the old frame pointer
    movl    %esp,   %ebp    #create the new frame pointer
    pushl   %ebx    #saving a callee save register.

leal -12(%ebp), %edx        #choice will be saved in edx
    pushl %edx
    pushl $strString    
    call scanf
    movl  (%edx), $stringToRev

    pushl   -12(%ebp)
    pushl   $strString
    call    printf
    call    Reverse

    pushl   %eax
    pushl   $strString
    call    printf
```

If I enter a string, for example "asfdg", it prints 0 (instead of this string).
I feel desperate about it- there is no answers for assembly in web!

Comment: What did you discover when you stepped through this with a debugger?

Comment: I'm a beginner in assembly. I'm not fluent in the debugger...

Comment: Then you should spend some time learning to use the debugger.  Debugging is probably 50% of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't have memory allocated for your string, so it is put somewhere random. I would suggest you reserve some space for your string in the data section and the push the pointer to this space to scanf as the argument.

If you are using a local stack variable, as you imply here:

```
pushl   -12(%ebp)
```

Then you must also reserve some stackspace for it, which you don't as can be seen here:

```
 pushl   %ebp    #save the old frame pointer
 movl    %esp,   %ebp    #create the new frame pointer
 pushl   %ebx    #saving a callee save register.

 leal -12(%ebp), %edx        #choice will be saved in edx
```

You are not reserving any space on the stack for your local pointer. And of course, you have to decide if it should be a pointer, then you still have to provide some space for the actual string, or put the whole string on the stack and reserve enough space there.